# How to show the text in label from left to right depending on whther or not there is another UI Element present

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, uilabel

I am trying to show some content in my Table view cell. I have an image on the left and I have to show some text (Description ) on the right. Everything is dynamic. So the length of the description if sometimes small and sometimes very very large.

Now, I have a Image view on the left and description on the right .Please find the below image for reference

[image: as shown in the figure].

I want to show the description occupy the entire tableview cell width if the description slides down even after the image view. How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use Auto-layout for this. You'll need to set the height and width constraints for your imageView. Don't specify width for your textview/label, instead specify the leading and trailing constraints for the it. Create an outlet for the width constraint of the imageview. If you don't have an image to display in the imageview add a condition check to set it to 0, otherwise set it to the constant value. If the imageview's width becomes zero, the textview will expand and it will decrease if the you set a constant value for the width constraint. Also, in your tableview delegate return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` in both `heightForRow` and `estimatedHeightForRow`.

Comment: You should also mention using `UITableViewAutomaticDimensions` to ensure all the rows resize based on text

Comment: @Rikh Thank you forgot that. Updated.